# how make handy decorator in python?

Tags: python

assume this decorator code :

#### first code:

```
def makeitalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return wrapped

@makeitalic
def hello():
    return "hello world"
    
print (hello())


<i>hello world</i>
```

I want to make this output handy by this code:

```
def makeitalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return wrapped

def hello():
    return "hello world"

hello()

'hello world'

makeitalic(hello)
<function makeitalic.<locals>.wrapped at 0x02C25AE0>
makeitalic(hello())
<function makeitalic.<locals>.wrapped at 0x02E902B8>
print(makeitalic(hello))
<function makeitalic.<locals>.wrapped at 0x02C25AE0>
```

but it just return obj.
is there any way to reach the first code output by this method ?

Comment: In what way is the second approach "handy"?

Comment: I recommend you use [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps()) decorator on your wrapper, it helps you preserve the wrapped function's name and docstring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
makeitalic(hello)()
```

Comment: @ZeroDays  to run a function you have to call it `makeitalic(hello)()` the extra() is calling the function `when you do makeitalic(hello) a function object is created in the memory but it is not called`